# The constructor IOSDriver<IOSElement>(Capabilitie) refers to the missing type capabilities

Tags: automation, appium

I'm getting below error when i try to initiate IOSDriver, Can you please let me know how to resolve this error, I tried with various constructor arguments mentioned for IOSDriver couldn't resolve it yet.

> The constructor IOSDriver(Capabilitie) refers to the missing type capabilities"

Appium Client library:  5.0.0- beta6

Below is my code snippet. When i try to initiate IOSDriver,

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone SE");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "10.3");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "iOS");
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APPIUM_VERSION, "1.6.5");
capabilities.setCapability("app", "/Users/sachin.kr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator");
capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");
driver = new IOSDriver<IOSElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your app path is incorrect, you should add .app the the end -

/Users/sachin.kr/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-brdadhpuduowllgivnnvuygpwhzy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator.app

(assuming you are using the simulator build).

Please also try removing  `<IOSElement>`

Comment: yeah, I had missed it in my app path, Hence it was throwing that error. Corrected it. Thanks :)